# How to use adapter for list of images in listview in xamarin C#

Tags: android-listview

I have ListView and I want to add images for it by using adapter:
this is the row axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="81.1dp"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="91.7dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Text"
        android:layout_width="184.9dp"
        android:layout_height="35.6dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
    <Button
        android:text="Chat"
        android:layout_width="62.3dp"
        android:layout_height="37.8dp"
        android:id="@+id/chat1"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
and this is the activity for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace EJIK_Network
{
    [Activity (Label = "FriendsActivity")]          
    public class FriendsActivity : Activity
    {
    ListView listview;
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Friends);
        listview = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);

        var friends= new [] { "Артём Соколов", "Лидия Чуйкина", "Наташка Чебурашка" ,   "Даша Митрофанова"};
        int [] image = {Resource.Drawable.next,Resource.Drawable.next,
            Resource.Drawable.next,Resource.Drawable.next };

        listview.Adapter=new ArrayAdapter                   (this,Resource.Layout.Row1,Resource.Id.textView1, friends);

        listview.Adapter=new ArrayAdapter (this,Resource.Layout.Row1,Resource.Id.imageView5, image);
        listview.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
    }
}
```

}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////
1-The code run. 
2-I have many layouts befor this and every thing good but when I click buttom to show list of friend with thier photo it gives me this error "Unfortunately ListView has stopped".
3-the error is between the list of images and the adapter: 
    int [] image = {Resource.Drawable.next,Resource.Drawable.next,      Resource.Drawable.next,Resource.Drawable.next};
     listview.Adapter=new ArrayAdapter (this,Resource.Layout.Row1,Resource.Id.imageView5,  image); 
4-In my example I have 4 friends:
    var friends= new [] { "Артём Соколов", "Лидия Чуйкина", "Наташка Чебурашка" ,                                                                  "Даша Митрофанова"};
5-I know that I use the same photo but doesn't matter .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Does your code run? What error do you get? What does the code do when it runs? What do you want it to do? You have to make sure to address all of these questions for us to be able to help you...otherwise, we don't really know what you're even asking.

Comment: 1-Yes the code run. 2-I have many layouts befor this and every thing good but when I click buttom to show list of friend with thier photo it gives me this error "Unfortunately ListView has stopped".3-the error is between the list of images and the adapter: int [] image = {Resource.Drawable.next,Resource.Drawable.next,
            Resource.Drawable.next,Resource.Drawable.next};         listview.Adapter=new ArrayAdapter (this,Resource.Layout.Row1,Resource.Id.imageView5, image);      4-I know that I use the same photo but doesn't matter

Comment: go ahead and edit that into your question!